# Android Check Date format in the device

Tags: java, android, date

which is the best method for check the date format set in the device? a method similar to those for control `PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH` for exemple...something quick or immediate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but I know that dates stored in Android for `Events` of a Contact (such as Birthdays) are stored as a `String` in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, or `0000-MM-DD` if the year is not known. This is unfortunately undocumented. It would be my hope that all internal dates conform to the same structure, so as to help retain consistency across the whole environment.